# simple python regex issue

Tags: python, regex, csv

I am trying to write a small bit of code using the regex module that will remove a portion of a url from a .csv file and return the selected chunk as output.  if the section ends with .com/go/, I would like it to return the content AFTER "go".  Here's the code:

```
import csv
import re

with open('rtdata.csv', 'rb') as fhand:
    reader = csv.reader(fhand)
    for row in reader:
        url=row[6].strip()
        section=re.findall("^http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/(.*/)", url)
        if section==re.findall("^go.*", url):
            section=re.findall("^http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/go/(.*/)", url)

        print url
        print section
```

and here's some sample input-output:

1. Example 1

   1. input: `http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/go/news/videos/`
   2. output: `news/videos`
2. Example 2

   1. input: `http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/new-cars/`
   2. output: `new-cars`

what am I missing here?

Comment: a csv file with various columns.  the column I want to read is in position [6] of the string python reads in.

Comment: I'm not fluent in Python, but it seems like the "if section==re.findall("^go.*", url):" line is actually matching against the original url, not the subpart found at the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is failing because of the `^` in your second regex.  `go` is not at the start of the url, and so the match is failing.

Changing `"^go.*"` to `"go.*"` should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
s = re.search('http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/(go/)?(.*)/', url)
section = s.group(2)
```

instead of

```
    section=re.findall("^http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/(.*/)", url)
    if section==re.findall("^go.*", url):
        section=re.findall("^http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/go/(.*/)", url)
```

A visual illustration of the regex used:

`http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/(go/)?(.*)/`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ay-asMKaWZKDaJo0)

Comment: still doesn't seem to be working, I'll try the debuggex tool and see if I can't take a look at it from a different angle

Comment: Welcome to SO! I edited your question to make the examples clearer - please edit it back if that's not what you meant! I've now revised my answer - let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see elsewhere, the correct way to do what you were doing.

```
section=re.match("^http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/(.*/)", url).group(1)
if re.match("^go.*", section):
    section=re.match("^go/(.*/)", section).group(1)
```

Better yet, you should do all of this with a single regex:

```
section=re.match("^http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/(go/)?(.*/)", url).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze directly the content of the file, without reading with the scv module capabilities:

```
import re

tata = '''0,1,2,3,4,5, http://www.gagal.com/go/zui ,kkll
00,10,20,30,40,50, http://hardo.fr/glut/popolo , ocean
000,100,200,300,400,500,  http://debeny.cz/rutu/padu/go/gemini/sun=
00,01,02,03,04,05,http://www.klemperer.com/discs/major
000,100,200,300,400,500,  http://www.julia.ch/go/snowy/trf
'''

r = re.compile('^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,'
               ' *(http://[^ ,\n]+?(?:/go/([^ ,\n]+))?(?=[ ,\n]))',
               re.MULTILINE)

print tata

for g1,g2 in r.findall(tata):
    print '%s\n%s\n' % (g1,g2 if g2 else g1)
```

result

```
0,1,2,3,4,5, http://www.gagal.com/go/zui ,kkll
00,10,20,30,40,50, http://hardo.fr/glut/popolo , ocean
000,100,200,300,400,500,  http://debeny.cz/rutu/padu/go/gemini/sun=
00,01,02,03,04,05,http://www.klemperer.com/discs/major
000,100,200,300,400,500,  http://www.julia.ch/go/snowy/trf

http://www.gagal.com/go/zui
zui

http://hardo.fr/glut/popolo
http://hardo.fr/glut/popolo

http://debeny.cz/rutu/padu/go/gemini/sun=
gemini/sun=

http://www.klemperer.com/discs/major
http://www.klemperer.com/discs/major

http://www.julia.ch/go/snowy/trf
snowy/trf
```